# Remove unused Boolean literal

Tags: apex

I'm trying to fix some PMD issues and I'm working on PMD issue : Remove the unnecessary boolean literal

This is the line I'm trying to refine:

```
abc.isRequired = xyz.Status__c == 'Required' ? true : false;
```

I have written as below:

```
abc.isRequired  = xyz.Status__c == 'Required' ;
```

Is my refined line of code correct as original? If not, how to fix this issue **PMD issue : Remove the unnecessary boolean literal** on this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `==` results in boolean value. Scroll down to see the description here [Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) including some useful notes.